# atoi function in C

Tags: c

Question in C : given a number in character array , find the biggest two digit number (group of two digits should be checked from left to right) with the condition that the number cannot have same two digits . eg. input: 64998434 , output: 84 (not 99).

**Solution : atoi expects string not character array .
therefore just increase the array length by 1 and initialize it with terminating character as written below**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    char no[] = "64998434";
    int big = 0, temp, j = 0, length;

    length = strlen(no);
    //char str[2] = "";  // not working
    char str[3] = "\0";  // working

    if (length <= 0 || length == 1)
    {
        printf("Invalid input");
        return 0;
    }
    else if (length == 2)
    {
        printf("%d", atoi(no));
        return 0;
    }


    //loop to get two digits from input array and store in another array to convert into 
    //integer and than save and check for bigger number

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i += 2)
    {
        str[j] = no[i];
        str[j + 1] = no[i + 1];
        if (str[0] != str[1])
        {
            temp = atoi(str);
            if (temp > big)
            {
                big = temp;
            }
        }
        j = 0;
    }

    if (big != 0)
    {
        printf("%d\n", big);
        return 0;
    }
}
```

[image]

Comment: And with a choice between your code, pythontutor (whatever that is) and a compiler used by millions to develop billions of lines of code in real world applications, you think the compiler is at fault?  Occam's Razor suggests that _your code_ is not behaving the way _you expect_. It is not the compiler at fault.  Apart from that, surely the answer required is 98 (neither 99 nor 84)?  Presumably the pythontutor code is Python not C, so irrelavant to this question?  There are in any case multiple compilers for both platforms, you would need to specify if you believe the compiler to be at fault.

Comment: `str` is not a string it is a two character array. To be a string it needs a terminator and `atoi()` expects a string.  Why use `atoi()` in any case, or `str` for that matter? Consider `temp = (no[I] - '0') * 10 + no[I + 1] - '0' ;`.  Or you could simply use `strncmp()` and not convert to an integer at all.

Comment: whats the actual question here?

Comment: Please don't answer your own question inside your question. You can post an answer to your question (which you have already done).

Answer (score 0):

`str` is an array of length `2`. You store potentially non-null characters in both of the array slots (`j` is always `0` in your code):

```
    str[j] = no[i];
    str[j + 1] = no[i + 1];
```

Then you pass it to `atoi`, which expects a null-terminated string. But `str` now has no null character anymore and therefore the behavior is undefined.

`str` should have length `3`, not `2`.

(This may not be the only issue with your code.)

Answer (score 0):

`atoi` does not seem required for this task.

Here is a simple solution using `strncmp()`:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main() {
    char str[] = "649984343497864236666784328253489";
    int i, imax = -1, len = strlen(str);
    for (i = 0; i + 2 <= len; i += 2) {
        if (str[i] != str[i + 1] && (imax < 0 || strncmp(str + i, str + imax, 2) > 0)) {
            imax = i;
        }
    }
    if (imax < 0)
        printf("no solution\n");
    else
        printf("%.2s\n", str + imax);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a single pass should do it.

```
// Return -1 on error
// Otherwise return the value of the biggest pair
int biggest_pair(const char *s) {
  int biggest = -1;
  while (s[0]) {
    // This and next character a digit?
    if (!(s[0] >= '0' && s[0] <= '9' && s[1] >= '0' && s[1] <= '9')) {
      return -1;
    }
    int test = (s[0] - '0')*10 + s[1] - '0';
    // Are digits different and this is larger than the current best?
    if (s[0] != s[1] && test > biggest) {
      biggest = test;
    }
    s += 2;
  }
  return biggest;
}
```

---

Code could use `isdigit()`.

```
int biggest_pair(const char *s) {
  const char *us = (const char *) s;
  int biggest = -1;
  while (us[0]) {
    // Check this and next character as digits?
    if (!(isdigit(us[0]) && isdigit(us[1])) {
      return -1;
    }
    int test = (us[0] - '0')*10 + us[1] - '0';
    // Are digits different and this is larger than the current best?
    if (us[0] != us[1] && test > biggest) {
      biggest = test;
    }
    us += 2;
  }
  return biggest;
}
```

This 2nd version also properly distinguishes +0 from -9 on those rare non-2's complement machines.